# how to draw pie chart in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, pie-chart, chartkick

I have to `models`. `Employee` and `locations` . the `association` between them is `location` has many `employees`. and `employee` belongs to `location`. i want to draw a `pie` chart between this `2` models. means i want to show all `locations` and `employees` `count` of that `location` in `pie chart`. how can i do that?

i was trying to implement this using the `Chartkick gem`.

but do not know how to draw the graph between them.

Answer (score 0):

Try `gruff` or `rchar` both should work in your case.

https://github.com/topfunky/gruff

https://github.com/amardaxini/rchart

Answer (score 0):

In order to have piechart by using Chartkick gem we can use the method

```
pie_chart *argument
```

*argument is nothing but a hash with count of each key values

in your case you can do something like this

```
 pie_chart Location.includes(:employees).collect{|loc| {"#{loc.name}".to_sym => loc.employees.size}}.reduce Hash.new, :merge
```

it will return a hash with keys like "location name" and values to respective keys will be the employees count